# Unable to expand a variable used in cURL command

Tags: shell

I need to use a variable inside the cURL command. The variable needs to be placed in a JSON string used by cURL. The problem is that, when used in the JSON String, the variable it's not expanded to its value:

```
export line="job1"

curl -k -X POST https://jenkinsserver \
--data-urlencode json='{"parameter": [{"name":"jenkins.job.name", "value":"$line"}]}'
```

I've tried also using:

```
"${line}"
```

But it didn't help. Instead of the variable's value, it's passing just "$line".
Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Don't use shell interpolation to generate JSON; use a tool like `jq`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `"'"$line"'"` and see if it works

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick!

Comment: This fails if `$line` contains any character that needs to be escaped for proper JSON.

Answer (score 1):

I know there is a duplicate for this somewhere, but I can't find it.

Use a tool like `jq` to generate your JSON safely, no matter what the value of `line` is.

```
d=$(jq -n --arg x "$line" '{parameter: [{name: "jenkins.job.name", "value": $x}]}'

curl -k -X POST https://jenkinsserver --data-urlencode json="$d"
```